# How can i remove support for iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, xcode4.5

How can i remove support for ios 6?
My app is not capable of supporting iOS 6 resolution and i dont want to stretch it.
I am using ios 6 sdk.
Need some assistance for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: iOS 6 doesn't introduce a new resolution. Maybe you meant iPhone 5. Also, if your app doesn't support it, it **will no be stretched.** It will have a black bar at the top and the bottom.

Comment: yes the black strip is coming from both sides ..

Answer (score 3):

Just don't add a Default-h586.png image to your app, and it will run with black bands at the top and bottom.

Comment: will it be ok with apple? i am worried about rejecting due to this.

Comment: You'll have to read the appstore guidelines for that. It's something I imagine the AppStore Uploader should tell you about straight away when you try to upload, but my app supports iOS6 so I don't know...